# Xamarin Forms - Lottie Animation - CarouselView

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, lottie

I'm using the latest version of Xamarin Forms and Lottie package.
I'm trying to bind lottie animation in carouselview. The problem is lottie animation start after i have scrolled all the slides. (if i not scroll the animation is blank)
my carouselview xaml is:

```
<CarouselView
            PositionChanged="TheCarousel_PositionChanged"
            x:Name="TheCarousel"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            IndicatorView="indicatorview">
            
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <AbsoluteLayout>
                            <StackLayout 
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=
                            "0.5,0.3,AutoSize,AutoSize"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags=
                            "PositionProportional"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            >

                                <forms:AnimationView
                                    x:Name="animationView"
                                    Animation="{Binding animazione}"
                                    AnimationSource="EmbeddedResource"
                                    CacheComposition="True"
                                    AutoPlay="{Binding autoplay}"
                                    RepeatMode="Infinite"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

                                <Label
                                FontSize="Title"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{Binding testo}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />



                            </StackLayout>
                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

and i populate it via code:

```
TheCarousel.BatchBegin();
intro = new ObservableCollection<Intro>();
var intro1 = new Intro { color1 = Color.Red, color2 = Color.Red, testo = "Hello 1", animazione = "Assets.71216-delivery-guy.json", autoplay = true };
var intro2 = new Intro { color1 = Color.RosyBrown, color2 = Color.Red, testo = "Hello 2", animazione = "Assets.pagamento-carte.json", autoplay = true };
intro.Add(intro1);
intro.Add(intro2);
TheCarousel.ItemsSource = intro;
TheCarousel.BatchCommit();
```

Why this happen ?

Comment: Had you tried to load the Animation in the other controls? In addition, can you make sure that when the CarouselView appears, the Animation had been load? This issue may be caused by the animation need time to load.

Comment: Yes if i put the animation out the carouselview it loads immediately. i notice these things:
1)when the app starts and you don't do anything and so stop to the first slide you can stay so still for hours that the animation doesn't appear also if you scroll to the second slide and wait here.
2) The animation starts only when you swipe all the slides and turn the first slide

Comment: This is a strange issue. I still think the reason is when the CarouselView item appears, the animation doesn't load completely. So just when you swipe all the slides, all the animations load completely.

Comment: You can test it by adding more carouselview items such as 7. When it scroll to 5, you can scroll back to 2 or 1to check the animation displaying or not.

Comment: Resolved!! it was the AbsoluteLayout Control.. I've used Grid instead and now it works correctly !